# Question regarding multi router in angular11

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a question here, I don't know have I follow the best practice of the angular even it is works now:

here is the structure of this nested component:
pages

[image]

and here is my **app-routing.module.ts** file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [{ path: 'team', component: TeamComponent }],
  },

  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**So, team component is the sub component of Admin component, there is a navigation bar in Admin component and it will render the team component inside.**

Code for Admin component:

```
<app-nav-admin></app-nav-admin>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Code for navigation bar href to team component HTML:

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="admin/team">Team management</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

and result after click on team link:
[image]

as you can see in href value, I assigned ""admin/team"" to go to team component and it really works, but is this is the best practice?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting there almost. However, now if on one page you need the `FormsModule` because you want to use the `NgModelDirective` in your template, you will be loading the `FormsModule` for each page in the `AppModule`, even when you don't need it. Best practice is to implement route-level code-splitting, eg. use one module per page.

You can use the following command to generate pages:

```
ng g module register --module account --route account
```

This will generate both a module and component that allows you to separate your dependencies. Full example:

```
cd app
ng g module pages --module app --route /
cd pages
ng g module account --module pages --route account
cd account
ng g module register --module account --route register
ng g module login --module account --route login
ng g module profile --module account --route profile
```

Make sure that

- the `PagesModule` is **not** imported in the `AppModule`
- the `AccountModule` is **not** imported in the `PagesModule`
- the `RegisterModule`, `LoginModule`, and `ProfileModule` are **not** imported in the `AccountModule`

It also allows you to have a shared html banner or snippet whenever you're on any page related to, say account settings. In your case this would be in **admin.componrnt.html**:

```
<app-nav-admin></app-nav-admin>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You will notice that the size of your `main.xxxxxx.js` (main bundle) decreases drastically), so your app will load faster. However when navigating, the other modules needed for the other page aren't loaded yet, so you will experience a delay. To resolve this, you can use the `preloadingstrategy: PreloadAllModules` in the options of your `RouterModule.forRoot()` call (app-routing.module.ts)

Also note that the resulting `AccountRoutingModule` has the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: () => import('./register/register.module').then(m => m.RegisterModule) },
  { path: 'profile', loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule) },
];
```

The `import('')` instruction decouples your modules, while still allowing strong-type-checking. So the modules do not need to be `import`ed in the `AccountModule`.

As a sidenote, you can you Lighthouse, which is built-in in Chrome, to evaluate your website. It will detect that you have an angular app, and one of the suggestions will be the use of route-level code-splitting. Since Lighthouse detects that the entire javascript application is loaded at once, including modules it doesn't need at that time. To use Lighthouse, in Chrome simply press F12 to open developer tools, and there will be a tab *Lighthouse*.

Comment: thanks for your comprehensive explaination!!!
I know this is a bit much requirement, but if you have time, could you please create a code sample for me for a few minutes so that I can more easily understand your design and layout structure? Your explanation seems a little abstract to me

Comment: Sorry, but I think the code you wirte here has a small error:
ng g module register --module account --route register
ng g module register --module account --route login
ng g module register --module account --route profile
The second line and third one has the wrong module name right?

Comment: I watch the video on Youtbe and learned the Lazy load and Router and feature module
I want to say thank you so much for your comment and it really help me improving on Angular!

Comment: If you want to have a real-life example, [here is one](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/tree/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/app/pages/account) where I implemented the exact same module

Comment: Hi @Pieterjan,
I followed the step and convert my app to lazyloading and using light house to check, but currently I am facing a wired issue. Once I click on second navbar - Team management, it successfully redirect to team conmponent, but the second navbar disappear. 
I created a new questions regarding this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68513105/angular-second-layer-navigation-dispear-after-click-on-link
Can you give a check if you have time? I do use router-outlet at Admin level but it seems like not working...

Answer (score 2):

Your approach work, but I recommend use modules (https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules) for good implementation in your projects.

For example, you could have an Admin Module and this module would have its own router. In this way, you have more control of the routes and child components also you can implement lazy loading too.

Comment: This will still load your entire application on initial load. Lazy-loading modules is preferred.

Comment: @Pieterjan Yeah that's true.

Comment: These are things that I learnt about 6 months ago when launching Lighthouse against my own website. It's really an impressive tool. Before then, I just didn't know about, or didn't realise that these type of optimizations even existed.