# Angular Second Layer Navigation dispear after click on link

Tags: lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have two layer navbar and the app is using Lazy loading, but every time I clcik on Team Management button the component is working but the Admin Panel navbar is dispear:
[image]

Here is my ***admin-routing.module.ts:***

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AdminComponent },
  {
    path: 'team',
    loadChildren: () => import('./team/team.module').then((m) => m.TeamModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {}
```

Here is HTML for the ***admin.component.html***:

```
<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin Panel</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#team-navbarNav"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="team-navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/team" routerLink="team"
              >Team Management</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Others</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is the result of after click on ***Team Management button:***

[image]

As you can see the second navbar is gone, I do set up

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

in admin.component.html, but it feels like never works..

team is the sub component of admin.

***admin-routing. module.ts:***
[image]

[image]

Here is my Github repo:

```
https://github.com/qwe3804132/BusyQA-CRM/tree/main/CRMFrontEnd
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I'll take a look

Comment: Can you tell how we can run your java backend application?

Comment: Sorry it’s just provide the login function and jwt token. 
The first layer Navbar is control by one attribute- islogged is true. 
So if logged then you can see the admin panel on the first layer Navbar. 
You can change that condition in app.component.html.  
You don’t really need to connect or register on backend. 
I can also modify the code once I back home. Sorry for inconvenience